# Refs not rerunning after onAuthStateChanged changes Firebase 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The following code below attaches a watcher on the `users/` path and logs the users when the value changes.

On firebase, this `users/` tree is gated depending on the current authenticated users' access permissions.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  }
});

firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  // log the users
  console.log(snapshot.val())
});
```

The issue is after logging in with a user with correct permissions, the `users/` tree doesn't get logged as shown in the above callback.

Is there other solutions other than moving the `users/` observer inside the callback of `onAuthStateChanged`. That smells of memory leaks.

Comment: I'll write an educated guess below. But without seeing your security rules, it'll remain just that: an educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listeners to a node, the Firebase Database immediately evaluates whether the current connection has permission to read from that node. If it doesn't, it cancels the listener.

Since you start out unauthenticated, the listener is immediately cancelled. You can easily see this if you also pass an error callback into `on()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

To solve this problem, you need to attach the listener *after* the user has been authenticated:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    }, function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I make sure that these refs are cleaned up after a user logs out, for instance, or reconnects?

Comment: did  you solve it ? I have a lot of .on listeners in my app and I want to cancel the listeners on all of them.