# react-router replace function not being handled correctly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I have on `onEnter` hook calling this function:

```
function (nextState, replace) {
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            console.log('attempting to access a secure route');
            replace({
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
            })
            console.log('should have called replace');
        }
        unsubscribe();
    });
};
```

Both `console.log` statements are executed. The `replace` function is definitely defined; however, the routes are not replaced.

Source question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370599/firebase-auth-delayed-on-refresh#comment62253343_37370599) whose core motive is slightly different. However, they are sort of related, but I wanted the titles different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase.auth()` is async, so you need to define a callback on `onEnter`:

```
function (nextState, replace , callback /*** <== add this ***/ ) {
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            console.log('attempting to access a secure route');
            replace({
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
            })
            console.log('should have called replace');
            callback(); /*** <=== call this to change route ***/
        }
        unsubscribe();
    });
};
```

According to the doc: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#user-content-onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore