# angularjs firebase onAuthStateChanged signout the database error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I sign out of the app, I get this error:

```
Error: permission_denied at /users/KuehJHDJ15SfS1s6FIh1: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

 at G (firebase.js:432)
    at Object.G (firebase.js:456)
    at Pg (firebase.js:398)
    at Eg.g.wd (firebase.js:391)
    at sg.wd (firebase.js:381)
    at bg.hg (firebase.js:379)
    at eg (firebase.js:363)
    at WebSocket.La.onmessage (firebase.js:362)
```

I suspect that my question is very much related to this here:
[Refs not rerunning after onAuthStateChanged changes Firebase 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370462/refs-not-rerunning-after-onauthstatechanged-changes-firebase-3-0-0)

here are my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null && root.child('hashlist/'+root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/hash').val()).val() == auth.email",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "hashlist": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() == 'admin'"

    }
  }
}
```

i would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Yep. It's related, but it's the reverse: you need to call `off` on the listening ref's before you sign out.

Comment: @cartant what should I do exactly? can you give an example?

Comment: @cartant how do i find my listening refs? because i have some 50 of them by now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are thrown because there are refs that continue to listen for changes after the sign out has occurred and, once signed out, the security rules are preventing them from doing so.

To prevent the errors, you will need to call `off` on any refs that are listening before signing out.

There is no automated facility for doing this; it's something you have to manage yourself. You should:

- Use `$scope.$on("$destroy", ...)` to switch off listening refs in scopes when there are no longer required (it's been a long time since I've used Angular JS, so my memory could be a little unreliable here).
- Make sure you don't leave dangling listeners by using `once` in situations in which you only need to read a value once.
- Consider using [`AngularFire`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire), which provides some nice bindings for objects and arrays and will wire itself up (if I remember correctly) so that its internal listening refs are switched off when scopes are destroyed.