# Permissions denied after logout

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

I build an AngularJs (1.6) app with a firebase database. Problem is: when a user logs out, I get a ton of errors `permission_denied`.

If that can be of any help:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    $state.go('login');
}, function(error) {});
```

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs firebase onAuthStateChanged signout the database error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927506/angularjs-firebase-onauthstatechanged-signout-the-database-error)