# Angularfire2: Permission_denied on logout

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

When I call this method:

```
login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      });
}
```

I get the following error (when logging out):

```
zone.js:915 Uncaught Error: permission_denied at /users/{uid}: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

However, if I change my `login()` method thusly:

```
login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())

}
```

I get no error.

1) what is wrong with my first login method.
2) what is the proper way to do something after a login with angularfire2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs firebase onAuthStateChanged signout the database error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927506/angularjs-firebase-onauthstatechanged-signout-the-database-error)

Comment: Bit different, that is angularjs, this is angular. I also don't think I'm subscribing to anything like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then
```

The way I see it you try to log in and THEN do something. The thing is that the login is async and just because u put "then" doesn't mean it will execute after login. Try to implement the "then" at `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: I moved my navigate to a guard (and it still doesn't work). Do you think I should move it there?

Comment: @Jeff Give it a try, I had the same problem and it helped. Check if(currentUser) and paste the "then" code

Comment: So I think the issue is that my guards are `Observable<boolean>`s and for whatever reason, that prevents my navigation.